# MacOS default folders missing

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, folders

I noticed, I am missing some of my default folders in the finder (Public, Sites, Movies, Library).

However I can list them in the terminal and enter them with the `cd` command.

I tried to use `chflags nohidden`, to make them visible in the finder again, but nothing happened.

Is there any other way, to make them visible again in the finder?

Edit:[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you miss them, in the sidebar or in the content part itself? If unsure, just add a screenshot please.

Comment: In the sidebar and in the content part itself. Screenshot attached. A Movies folder is actually there (Filme), but it seems not to be the correct one, as I see a folder Movies and the folder Filme in the terminal.

Comment: Did you restore your home folder from backup or similar recently

Comment: I do not remember, when I restored everything from a Time Machine Backup, it must have been quite a long time. However I do not remember as well, when I last saw those folders.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a **permissions problem**.

```
diskutil resetUserPermissions / `id -u`
```

After entering the `diskutil` command, if Terminal says that permissions reset on user home directory failed (error -69841), enter `chflags -R nouchg ~` and enter the `diskutil` command again.

You can also double-check whether your user **Library** folder is set properly. Open Finder as root:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
```

Now navigate to your home folder, click on Library folder > cmd+J > check the box for "Show Library folder".

Let us know whether this solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks, the Library folder is back. The rest of the folders - Public, Movies, Sites - is still missing.